# Oracle 11g database with 9i Client

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle9i

I would know if it could works like this:

```
Database 11G R2 on Windows 2008 R2 x64
Oracle Client 9i (what version?) for OCI connection on 11g ?
```

I heard that we can use 9.2.0.4 for connection to 11G R2 database, but if you have an tutorial or if you can describe the way to do, i would be glad !

Because we are running on 9i database with 9i client ... on 2003 R2 x86.

Connection must be possible with Navicat or i would not be able to work fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 9i client has been patched to at least 9.2.0.4 (note that most people do not apply patchsets to client machines which would be necessary here), a connection to an 11.2 database should be no different than a connection to any other version of the database.  I've never heard of Navicat but I assume it's just using the standard Oracle client libraries to connect to a database.